Having a password generator use user input to for generation of password with set parameters
I am trying to create a password generator program where the user can select for example 8 special characters, 5 uppercase letters and 10 lowercase letters to be generated into a password. So for the above example the password would be 23 characters long with 8 special characters, 5 uppercase letters and 10 lowercase letters. I have the input created but what I am unsure of is how to get the program to know that for example 8 special characters will be 8 random characters from string.punctuation for example.
This a sample code of how I am asking the user for their input.
while True:
  try:
    lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    lower_low = 6
    lower_high = 24
    lower_choice = int(input("How many lower case letters would you like in your password? "))
    if lower_choice<lower_low or lower_choice>lower_high:
      print("The selection must be" ,lower_low,"or higher or", lower_high,"and lower. Please choose again. ")
      continue
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input. Please try again.")

print("You have choosen", lower_choice,"lowercase letters to be used in your password.")

I tried creating a function like the one below to see if it would take user inputs and match the number to string.punctuation for example and then create a random selection based on that but I am going wrong.
def password_gen():
  special = (string.punctuation)
  lower_choice = (string.ascii_lowercase)
  upper_choice = (string.ascii_uppercase)
  password = ''
  for p in range(38):
    password += random.choice(special+lower_choice+upper_choice)
    return password
  password = password_gen

  print(password)

Where should I look first to point me in the right direction?

Loop once for each type of character the user asked for, looping the number of times they asked. Saving the random.choice into a string or list. Don't return until after all the looping. Returning in a loop will cause the function to immediately end in the first iteration.
